# Git runner - problem to download dependency

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have one project that uses the git runner.

The command `mvn package` works fine on local, all dependencies are downloaded from my local nexus.

When I execute build command at the git runner environment, all dependencies from my local nexus where downloaded without problem too, but only one dependency is a problem, lets see:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sic: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:sic:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at br.com.sspds:ojdbc6:jar:1.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for br.com.sspds:ojdbc6:jar:1.0.1: Could not transfer artifact br.com.sspds:ojdbc6:pom:1.0.1 from/to Nexus (http://172.25.100.75:8090/repository/maven-public/): Transfer failed for http://172.25.100.75:8090/repository/maven-public/br/com/sspds/ojdbc6/1.0.1/ojdbc6-1.0.1.pom: No route to host (Host unreachable)
```

One big detail: the library `ojdbc6-1.0.1.jar` was developed by our team and made available manually on our nexus server.

My configuration from nexus server is into my pom.xml.

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Looks like a network issue...

Comment: If this is within company network, then maybe you need to set in runner global maven configuration properly proxy settings: http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy.